# How to add two validators for a Text Form Field to accept and validate a email or a phone number?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to validate phone number / email address to be entered by the user in a single text form field as soon as user enters the value.I have tried using various methods of validation but this is how close I have got, still returning with errors. I want the user to either enter a email address or a phone number to get an OTP on either one for logging in the app. I am attaching an image of the [ui screen][1] to show what I want to achieve.  I have tried defining final global key in main.dart as:

``````````````````````````````````````````
 MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
//  _formKey and _autoValidate
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool _autoValidate = false;
  String _name;
  String _email;
  String _mobile;

`````````````````````````````````````````
I want to validate inputs on my login page and it is returning with errors in the areas highlight in bold text.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  LoginPageState createState() => LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
 
  **Widget _showLoginInput() {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
        child: TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Enter phone number/email id',
          hintText: 'Enter phone number/email id',
          
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          validator: validateEmail,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            _email = val;
          },
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          validator: validateMobile,
          onSaved: (String val) {
            _mobile = val;
          },
        
        ));
  }
  String validateMobile(String value) {
// Indian Mobile number are of 10 digit only
    if (value.length != 10)
      return 'Mobile Number must be of 10 digit';
    else
      return null;
  }
  String validateEmail(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
      return 'Enter Valid Email';
    else
      return null;
  }**

 

  Widget _showOTPAction() {
    return Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          textColor: Colors.white,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    colors: [
                  Colors.blue[700],
                  Colors.blue,
                  Colors.deepPurple[700]
                ])),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: const Text(
              'GET OTP',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[

          Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
              **child: new Form(
              key: _formKey,
              autovalidate: _autoValidate,**
              
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 180.0,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          
                          **children: <Widget>[
                            _showLiteTitle(),
                            _showAddressTitle(),
                            
                            _showLoginInput(),
                            _showSkipAction()
                          ],**
                        ))
                  ]))),
          _showOTPAction(),
        ]));
  }
}


 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZQIx.png
``````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 1):

I would say if you want to check when the user types, then add the validation on onChanged rather than on onSave.

```
 onChanged: (v) {
                 _formKey.currentState.validate();
                            },
```

This is a simple validator without any regex :

```
 validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter email';
                              }
                       if (!value.contains('@') || value.length < 5) {
                         return 'Enter Valid Email';
                              }
                         return null;
                     },
```

Comment: ok , thank you but still how to add 2 validation in a single text form field

Comment: I did not get what you asked, like why are we doing two validations in a single textField?

Comment: I want to give user the flexibilty of either login with the help of phone number or with email.  Once the data input is validated that the given data is a valid phone number /email an OTP will be sent to the either one for logging in. I would like you to check the image of the login I have attached with my post to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: I got what you are trying to achieve. But I don't know how effective it can be. What I would suggest is make two TextFormField and then a button or something so that the user can select what type he is going to type and according to that change the TextFormField.

Comment: it could be a wise approach to add 2 text form field, but design choice has already been made, so I have to get it done this way, and I also want to know if possible how can it be done using single text form field but adding 2 validation.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
  String validate(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (regex.hasMatch(value))
      return null;
    else {
      if (value.length == 10)
        try {
          int.parse(value);
          return null;
        } catch(e) {
          return 'Enter valid email address/phone number';
        }
      else
        return 'Enter valid email address/phone number';
    }
  }
```

Comment: please clarify int i defination and catch (e), how to set it up to use the code suggested by you\

Comment: @GauravSharma I used ```int i = int.parse(value)``` to see if all characters in ```value``` are numbers or not.

Comment: It shows error "The value of the local variable 'i' isn't used."

Comment: And also if you could help me out with retrieving the data of Phone/Email entered by the user.

Comment: @GauravSharma I just edited my answer. in order to retrieve the data you can create a ```TextEditingController``` and pass it to your ```TextFormField```. then use previously created ```TextEditingController``` to retrieve the data. and also sorry for my English :)